# How to save and fetch integer value in Shared Preference in android?

Tags: android

> I want to save and fetch the static integer value of Snow Density in Shared Preferences and change when user select another value in the Single choice.
>    My Code :

```
public static int mSnowDensity;
AlertDialog.Builder mABuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AAA.this);
final CharSequence mCharSequence[] = { "Low", "Medium", "High" };
mABuilder.setTitle("Set Density of Snow");
mABuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(mCharSequence,
        WallpaperServices.mDensitySnow,
        new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 2) {

                    mSnowDensity = 90;
             /*I Want to save mSnowDensity Value In Shared Preferences */
                } else if (which == 1) {

                     mSnowDensity = 60;
                } else {

                     mSnowDensity = 30;
                }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Check this PrefUtils class https://gist.github.com/john1jan/b8cb536ca51a0b2aa1da4e81566869c4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use shared preferences as follows

```
//To save
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("SNOW_DENSITY",mSnowDensity);
editor.commit();

//To retrieve
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
int snowDensity = settings.getInt("SNOW_DENSITY", 0); //0 is the default value
```

getSharedPreferences() is a method of the Context class. If you are inside a Activity or a Service (which extend Context) you can use it like in this snippet. Else you should get the context using getApplicationContext() and then call getSharedPreferences() method.

For more options you can refer to the documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: How do you get those without context from anywhere?

Comment: @g00dy - By default it uses the context associated with the activity, the same which you get using getBasecontext()

Comment: by default yes, but what happens if you call it ouside of the `Activity`?

Comment: In that case you get the context as you described ;)

Comment: So, edit your answer, so that if it gets accepted and somebody at some point sees it - the answer can be correct when pasted into any given place :)

Comment: Special appreciation for mentioning "getSharedPreferences() is a method of the Context class". We all tend to forget that specially from SurfaceViews in game dev!

Answer (score 1):

**To save in the SharedPreferences:**

```
private final String PREFS_NAME  = "filename";
private final String KEY_DENSITY    = "den";

Context  ctx   = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

editor.putInt(KEY_DENSITY, mSnowDensity);
editor.commit();
```

**To get the value:**

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
String strSavedValue = null;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

strSavedValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("den", anyDefaultValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the value in prefrence

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

get the value from preference

```
 private void showPreferences(String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedPref = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0);

       }
```

You can use the key as the shared preference name

Answer (score 1):

**Initialization**
We need an editor to edit and save the changes in shared preferences. The following code can be used to get the shared preferences.

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 :- for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

**Storing Data**

```
editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); 
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); 
editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); 
editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value");
editor.putLong("key_name", "long value");  
editor.commit();
```

**Retrieving Data**

```
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("key_name", -1); // getting Integer
pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
```

**Clearing or Deleting Data**

```
editor.remove("name"); // will delete key name
editor.remove("email"); // will delete key email

editor.commit(); // commit changes


editor.clear();
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving preference is not a troubling task. But if you have a lot of such configurable options you could use a `PreferenceActivity` and override `onSharedPreferenceChanged`.

More details here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html