# store two string and one integer in shared preference using hashmap

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to store three values in shared preference

Can I store integer as third value in hashmap? As i passed null for string, what can i passed for integer?

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

        // user email id
        user.put(KEY_PASS, pref.getString(KEY_PASS, null));
        user.put(KEY_ID,pref.getInt(KEY_ID,));//what should i pass here??



        // return user
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save and fetch integer value in Shared Preference in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916873/how-to-save-and-fetch-integer-value-in-shared-preference-in-android)

Comment: The second argument for `get` function is just default values. It is the value that is returned, in case the preference hasn't been saved before.

Comment: @ShamasS what should be  default value if i am using getInt?

Comment: Default value should be something that your code can handle. You are setting `null` for string values, because you code must be checking for `null` values, if a `null` value is returned, it means there was no previously saved value. If my keyID, will never be -1, I would use -1 as a default value. And whenever -1 is returned, I will know that previously no value was saved.

Answer (score 0):

you've declared your `HashMap()` as a map that contains `String` objects, so, no, you can't really just store an integer in there.  However, you can convert the integer to a string if you like.  Since `getInt()` returns a primitive `int`, you should use the static method `Integer.toString(valuetomakeintoastring)`

The second value in your call to `getInt()` is the default value that should be returned if the `KEY` value is not found in the preferences.  Use some value that can't be confused as a valid value for your application.

`user.put(KEY_ID,Integer.toString(pref.getInt(KEY_ID,<somedefaultintegervalue>));`

Perhaps a `HashMap` is not the right data structure for you to use here?  Perhaps you really need to define a class that contains these values together, then create a HashMap of that class?

Comment: thank you...user.put(KEY_ID,Integer.toString(pref.getInt(KEY_ID,<somedefaultintegervalue>)); is working for me

Comment: excellent, glad to hear it.  If my answer solved your issue, please remember to "accept" the answer (click on the checkmark next to my answer).  that is the best way to say thank you on stack overflow!  :)