# fetch integer value from sharedpreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I use the following helper to save user input to sharedpreference:

```
protected void storeData(SharedPreferences.Editor editor,
                             String key, EditText et) {
        String content = et.getText().toString();
        if ("".equals(content)||" ".equals(content)) {
            editor.remove(key);
        } else {
            editor.putString(key, content);
        }
    }
```

then

```
number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

storeData(editor,"number1", number1);
 editor.commit();
```

I wish to ask if how can I retrieve that value as a integer, then use it for some calculation. 
I been searching and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916873/how-to-save-and-fetch-integer-value-in-shared-preference-in-android) , found that they use `editor.putInt(key,content);`

But is that possible to extract the value as integer straight from my method? 
thank you.

Comment: umm, `SharedPreferences.getInt(...)`?

Comment: I tried it, but it not working..

Comment: Pretty sure it does work otherwise the Android SDK is broken. We have no idea what your `storeData()` method does. You also show how you are trying to get it.

Comment: The `storeData()` is used to change the null value to default value, like if user put it blank , then it will save the value as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `storeData()` method is setting a string (`putString()`). Shared prefs store typed values distinctly different. That is, you cannot put "1" as a string then get it our later as an integer.

You need to use `put/getInt()` consistently. Alternatively you could store it as a string, and again consistently get it as a string and coerce it to an int as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your really should be using `putInt()`, but you can also use `Integer.parseInt("some string")` to convert your String value to an integer.

Comment: how to get the value out from sharepreference and related it to integer.parseInt ?

Answer (score 1):

Use editor.commit() inside the else part

A suggestion:
use editor.apply() instead of editor.commit() as commit handles the job in foreground whereas apply handles that asynchronously.

Comment: I tried it, along with  SharedPreferences.getInt(...) but it won't work as well..

Comment: Don't use SharedPreferences directly. Use like editing the object ob shared preference. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

I know, the question has been asked long time agao. I came up with similar situation. So, the might help someone in the future.

```
//for integer values

port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.devicePort);
int devicePort = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.devicePort), devicePort);
editor.apply();
```